# Distance from Tract Centroid to all County Border Pairs

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, distance, spatial-join

I am starting with a shapefile of census tracts and a shapefile of counties. I am trying to calculate the shortest distance from the centroid of every census tract to every county bordering the county containing the census tract. For example, say County A borders 4 other counties (B, C, D, and E), and suppose census tract X is in County A. The output table will have four rows for census tract X. One row will have the shortest distance from the centroid of tract X to the border of county B. There will be three additional rows for X to C, X to D, and X to E. This will be the case for every census tract in the US. I will need generate the same file for census blocks as well. Does anyone have a python script that could be useful for this or advice for a GIS newcomer with this complex task?

Comment: Your question might attract answers if you amend your question and include an image of what you are asking.